# View Page Android - pegar lista de imagens dentro do App e setar no View page.

Tags: java, array, android-studio

Galera estou com um problema quando eu preciso setar minha variavél no View Page.

Tenho um Activity que buscas as imagens dentro do App e seta em um Array de String, até então está tudo correto, uso o código abaixo.

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
// path to data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
new_folder = cw.getDir(pasta, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

if (!new_folder.exists()){
   new_folder.mkdir();
}
// verifica a pasta se tem arquivo //
files = new_folder.listFiles();

if ((files.length > 0)) {
   String[] fileArray = new String[files.length];
   int[] filesResource = new int[files.length];
   for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
      fileArray[i] = files[i].getAbsolutePath();
   }
}
```

Já na minha classe

```
public class CustomSwipeAdpter extends PagerAdapter {
```

Fiz um exemplo que vi em vários tutoriais que esta classe ja tem seus métodos prontos... onde eu tenho que usar um Array de Inteiro, que busca somente do drawable. assim:

```
private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.image01, R.drawable.image02, R.drawable.image03};
```

O que eu preciso realmente fazer é carregar todas as imagens que estão dentro do App para estas variável **image_resources**, eu consegui fazer até agora é carregar do caminho das imagens em um Array de strings, já tentei converter a variável **FileArray em Array de inteiro** mas da erro.

Se alguém tiver uma solução eu agradeço... ou se tiver um outro exemplo (tutorial, codigo) já ajuda. Valeu...

Comment: Aonde vai ser usado seu `array` `image_resources`?

Comment: será usado aqui 
'imageView.setImageBitmap(
                decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(resource,
                        image_resources[position], // aqui esta o problema
                        1080,
                        2560));'  
Antes eu estava usando o BitmapFactory.decodeFile mas estava dando problema...se tivesse alguma imagens com alta resolução da estouro de memória ai eu vi este metodo do site da Android que renderiza a imagem. 
Peguei neste site (http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possível solução seria usar o `objeto` [`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) e instânciar ele com seu `array` de  `String` dos `filepath`.

Este `objeto` cria um `drawable` a partir de um caminho e decodifica o `Bitmap`.

```
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(resource,fileArray[position]);
```

e no seu `ImageView`

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(bd);
```